# Serviços do azure - quais os reais casos de uso?

Tags: microsoft-azure

Não sei se essa pergunta está no escopo do SOpt, caso não esteja peço que me avisem pra eu deletar ou me digam como melhora-la. Estou desenvolvendo serviços RESTful com o ASP.NET WebAPI e aplicações de página única e pelo que pesquisei o Windows Azure é uma boa opção pra colocar isso tudo na internet.

O único problema é que não entendo como escolher o que contratar lá no site. Pesquisei muito e não consegui descobrir, daí resolvi perguntar. Basicamente, quando acesso a calculadora de preços tenho essas opções

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas o problema é que eu fico meio confuso com relação à qual opção usar. Eu sei que pode se compor com opções de mais de uma categoria, mas o preço acaba ficando absurdo, então acho que não é assim.

De certa forma, o que estou fazendo se enquadra em sites. Pesquisando mais no site do Azure encontrei isso sobre a opção sites:

> Hospede web sites, web APIs, aplicativos de tempo real, e aplicativos mobile.

Mas ao mesmo tempo, parece que se enquadra em serviços de nuvem, que diz

> Os Serviços de Nuvem permitem executar o código do aplicativo na nuvem implantando funções Web e de trabalho, com o Azure cuidando dos detalhes da implantação.

Mas ao mesmo tempo, eu preciso de base de dados, então se enquadra em gerenciamento de dados.

Estou começando agora no azure e não sei como funciona essa coisa de "pagar pelo que usar", porque tudo separado assim eu fico meio em dúvida o que deve ser escolhido.

Nesse caso, quais os reais casos de uso de cada uma dessas categorias e em qual deles se enquadra API's RESTful, SPA's e etc?

Answer (score 2):

A resposta é que você pode hospedar tanto em cloud services (web role) quanto em web sites. Existem algumas features que só funcionam em cloud services ex:

-vpn para a rede da sua empresa, por exemplo.

Uma outra coisa legal de cloud services. Você tem dois ambientes (staging / production), isto é, você pode publicar uma nova versão da api em staging, e após homologada, "virar a chave" para produção. Como o deployment já estará no datacenter do azure, é mais simples e rápido de publicar a mesma versão em production.

Obviamente há uma pequena variação no custo.

Em resumo acho que é isto, as duas opções te adentem.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @ThiagoCustodio. E por exemplo, se a aplicação é pequena e não necessita de muitos recursos no começo eu posso começar colocando ela em web sites e depois migrar sem dificuldades pra cloud services?

Comment: Depende do que você julga como "sem dificuldades". Seria necessário uma nova publicação. O domínio também seria alterado de ".azurewebsites.net" para ".cloudapp.net". Se você vai expor uma api para clientes, isto pode ser um problema.